# How can I compare pointers in Go?

Tags: pointers, go, comparison

I am building some test code and I try to compare pointers with the `<`, `>` operators. My goal is to order elements into a balanced tree structure (implemented by me). For that, I need quick, generic comparation. Following the good old C/C++ customs, my current idea is (*...was, at the time of writing this post*) to compare them by their pointer addresses.

However, as I've found, it doesn't work. The source

```
if (&(a.val) < &(b.val)) {
```

gives the compile error

> ./pointer.go:40: invalid operation: &a.val < &b.val (operator < not defined on pointer)

`a` and `b` are structs with `val` as (safe) pointer member.

Is it possible to compare safe pointers in go? How?

Is it guaranteed that the order of the pointers remains the same? (For example, I can imagine some GC trickery which also reorders the data.)

Comment: In Go there is no pointer arithmetic. What's the meaning of pointer `a` being less than pointer `b`? What possible information does it have that a memory address is less than another one?

Comment: Yes, you can get the address as a number or hex string, that's not the problem. It's that there is no sense in comparing the pointer values themselves.

Comment: Why would you care about the ordering of two values when answer you get is pretty much random? The information which particular address a pointer points to is meaningless without pointer arithmetic. In C (and I assume C++) pointers can only be compared when two pointers point to the same array (all other comparisons between pointers are undefined).

Comment: In C++ if `a` and `b` are pointers, then `if (a->val < b->val) { ... }` simply translates to `if (a.val < b.val) { ... }` in Go.

Comment: Yes I know, but in Go it works. `a.val` is a shorthand for `(*a).val`.

Comment: It's pretty trivial to convert a pointer to an integer and then compare the integers. But no one (including me) is telling you how to do it because we don't want to end up working with bad code that does things like that in case your code slips out or someone reads the answer and starts doing it.

Comment: Again, whether it's achievable has nothing to do with whether it makes sense. You still haven't stated what you're actually trying to accomplish here, but I'd bet there's a better way to achieve the end goal than trying to compare memory addresses.

Comment: Put another way: Doing a `<` or `>` comparison against pointers _never solves any problem_. So whatever problem you're trying to solve, must, by logical deduction, be solved some other way. So asking about your larger problem would naturally be a more fruitful way to find an answer.

Comment: Is the intent to use the address as some kind of hash ? In wich case it would indeed make sense. Basically that is what (some implementations of) python is doing to return the hash [ id() ] of objects.

Comment: @kriss I implemented a generic AVL tree, and I wanted this for a default comparison function. I tought (from C++) that comparing the pointers would be useful. I didn't know at the moment that allocated memory addresses can change in Go. Later that I learned that, and I used the equivalent of the C++ abstract class to implement it. I disliked the default go library from the first moment, particularly its hash implementation and that it is hard-wired into the language syntax, because I consider it VLQ. On these reasons, later I stopped to use Go any more.

Comment: Too bad, I'm pondering if I should use Go or not these days... I need some rock strong and very fast HTTP stack, and I'm rather worry to use some C++ library (not the common C++ use, henceforth I'm expecting troubles).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it guaranteed that the order of the pointers remains the same? (For
>   example, I can imagine some GC trickery which also reorders the data.)

In answer to this part of your question, it doesn't look like it. See pkg unsafe linked below.

If you want the memory address of a pointer, try the unsafe package:

https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/#Pointer

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    var a,b int
    var pa,pb *int
    pa = &a
    pb = &b

    //var c int
    //pa = &c

    if uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(pa)) < uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(pb)) {
      fmt.Printf("a:%p > b:%p",pa,pb)   
    } else {
      fmt.Printf("b:%p > a:%p",pb,pa)
    }

}
```

This will let you get an arbitrary Pointer type and then the *current* memory address of that pointer (as printf would). Note the caveats there though, you cannot rely on this address:

> Converting a Pointer to a uintptr produces the memory address of the
>   value pointed at, as an integer. The usual use for such a uintptr is
>   to print it. Conversion of a uintptr back to Pointer is not valid in
>   general. A uintptr is an integer, not a reference. Converting a
>   Pointer to a uintptr creates an integer value with no pointer
>   semantics. Even if a uintptr holds the address of some object, the
>   garbage collector will not update that uintptr's value if the object
>   moves, nor will that uintptr keep the object from being reclaimed.

**This bypasses the Go type system and memory security so it's unsafe and you probably don't want to do it**, unless you're just experimenting. I can't think of a reason to do it in tests, but if you want to be sure to read that entire document and be very sure you know that what you are doing will work as you expect.

Comment: I didn't recommend unsafe :) I think sometimes it's worth explaining why it is unsafe, as well as how to do it, so that people can make informed decisions... and maybe learn a little about the go memory model too.